# Almost sure convergence of random variable vecctors.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_n,Y_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a vector of random variables such that $(X_n,Y_n) \to (X,Y)$ almost sure.

This means that $$\Bbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega:(X_n(\omega),Y_n(\omega)) \to (X(\omega),Y(\omega))\})=1$$ or

$$\Bbb{P}(\{(\omega_1,\omega_2) \in \Omega^2:(X_n(\omega_1),Y_n(\omega_2)) \to (X(\omega_1),Y(\omega_2))\})=1$$

And why!

Comment: The former is the right formulation because that is the definition of a.s. convergence.

Comment: Former is the first or the second? (English is not my native language, haha)

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado The first one.